# 00904 When Creating Table

Tags: oracle, ddl

Here is the code I'm using in Oracle SQL Developer :

CREATE TABLE ORDER_ITEMS(
   ITEM_NO           NUMBER(10),
   ITEM_DESCRIPTION  VARCHAR(50),
   SIZE              VARCHAR(5),
   COST              NUMBER(8,2),
   QUANTITY          NUMBER(10),
   TOTAL             NUMBER(8,2),
   ITEM_ORDER_NO     NUMBER(10),
       CONSTRAINT ITM_NO_PK PRIMARY KEY (ITEM_NO));

The error has to do with the SIZE and COST tables, if I change the names on those two tables (for example put an A at the end of them (SIZEA COSTA)) then the code works. Why are these table names invalid ?

Comment: SIZE and COST are [Oracle Reserved Words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm) and [must be quoted](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements008.htm) to be used as identifiers. However, a table/columns called just "size" or "cost" could have a more refined named bestowed as well.. eg. 'ItemCost', perhaps.

Comment: Please remember to use VARCHAR2 in Oracle instead of VARCHAR as the behavior of the latter may change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean column where you're writing table. Also SIZE is a reserved word in Oracle SQL, as is NUMBER.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm

Comment: Yes I did mean column sorry. Thankyou for the feedback, I couldn't find that list but that solves it.